# Strange error while creating a convolution neural network

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

i want to create  convolutional neural network model in keras, first of all i have imported all necessary library  like this

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
```

than i have tried following  model

```
model =Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(filters=32,kernel_size=(5,5),padding='valid',input_shape=(1,28,28),activation='relu',data_format='channels_first'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(2,2, dim_ordering='tf'))
moodel.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Flattenn())
model.add(Dense(128,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(num_classes,activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy' , optimizer='adam' , metrics=['accuracy' ])
```

but i  have got following error :

```
TypeError: The added layer must be an instance of class Layer. Found: <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7faaefc57438>
```

could you help me please to fix this error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
moodel.add(Dropout(0.2))
```

Typo - `moodel` -> `model`

```
model.add(Flattenn())
```

Typo - `Flattenn` -> `Flatten`

And you should use `Convolution2D` instead of `Conv2D` import.

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Convolution2D

model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution2D(filters=32,...
```

Comment: i have done importing like this : from tensorflow.keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Dense, Conv2D, Flatten, Dropout, MaxPooling2D, BatchNormalization
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential

Comment: i fixed error thanks, so that means Convolutional2D is newest one right